# What's a good way to say "the front right 'side' of a car"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For context:

> There was a collision and the front left side of A's car hit the back right side of B's car.

The "front right" of a car isn't really a side so much as it is a corner, yet corner doesn't really sound good in the above context.

Comment: When it gets complicated, a diagram can help convey your intent. Otherwise, “front right” and “rear left” can work.

Comment: In the UK, the panel around the wheel, located at each corner of the car, used to be called the "wing", hence "right front wing" or similar, but this usage seems to have fallen out of fashion. (But "front right side" or "front right corner" seem easily understandable.)

Comment: Furthermore, in the UK, 'nearside' (left, passenger side) and 'offside' (right, driver side) are still in use. I believe the terms are not much used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the motor industry, your problem is solved by creating the adjectival noun phrases:

*Offside front, nearside front, offside rear, and nearside rear*.

See, for example,

[image]

> [Specialist Assessing Services](https://www.specialistassessing.co.uk/online_contact.php)

In this commonly used nomenclature, your particular front right side (or corner) is the “offside front”.

For those who dislike *offside* and *nearside*, I suggest they be trivially replaced by *passenger side* and *driver side*.

Comment: We (the minority) who drive on the proper side of the road, have be careful with this term because it comes from horse riding and, regardless of the side of the road people drive on, horse riders refer to the left side of the horse as the 'near' side and the right side as the 'off' side since riders always mount from the left. According to an American answer on [this forum](https://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Motoring/Question241036.html)  they say "driver side" and "passenger side" rather than "off" and "near" because "off " and "near" in our sense would be the wrong way round and just confusing.

Comment: driver side and passenger side seem common in the UK as well, probably for the same reason (as well as some people's inability to tell left from right).

Comment: Except that that doesn't work for LHD vehicles in a RHD country. For motoring, *nearside* and *offside* refer to the **kerb,** and are no longer related to horseriding (even though that's where the terms may have originated).

Comment: ... which makes horse-car collisions doubly problematic if they need reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any word there at all:

> The front left of A's car collided with the rear right of B's car.

If you insist on using a word, you can go with [quadrant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quadrant):

> any of the four quarters into which something is divided by two real or imaginary lines that intersect each other at right angles